# Featherlight gallery change previous and next arrows style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, featherlight.js

I'm using [featherlight gallery](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#featherlight-gallery) to display a bunch of images in a lightbox. Everything works amazingly, I would just like to change the style of the arrows.

Reading the docs, I see that I can easily change the icon of the arrows with any character, but i don't understand how to change other style elements.

For example, I would like to make the arrows black instead of white and fix them, not just make them appear on hover.

So far I have an ugly solution where I use js to change the style attributes, like so

```
document.getElementsByClassName("featherlight-next")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.color="black";
```

I'm a begginer with js, jquery, html and css, but I guess there must be a more elegant and practical solution.

I cannot change featherlight css since I'm loading it on the go from here:

```
cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.7.13/release/featherlight.gallery.min.js
```

Comment: Any CSS you load in the page will apply, as long as the selectors are correct (they match the element). You don't need to do it on the fly. To find out what selectors currently apply on your element, inspect it. You'll need to provide same selectors (if your CSS loads last) or stronger selectors otherwise. All you need is to inspect the CSS and overwrite what is currently being applied.

Comment: I will definitely try that, but I was wondering if there was a more "canonical" solution which I missed in the docs

Comment: Writing CSS to modify existing or future elements in the page is canonical. And quite basic: the bread and butter of web pages. From a web developer's perspective it's pretty much like expecting the `a` letter to show up at the caret when you press the `a` key. You won't find it written anywhere, yet people expect it to happen.

Comment: I didn't think about it, but it is actually the simplest solution. It works really well and it's much cleaner than using js. Thank you very much :-)